# Phalanger in asp.net Core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, phalanger

I have an app in asp.net core 1 and I need to use the [Responsive File Manager](http://www.responsivefilemanager.com/) for my tinymce editor so the user may upload files and images. For this I need to have phalanger to my app. I have add all the nessecary dll files and I did the settings in my web config file according to [this tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1004596/Using-Responsive-File-Manager-in-ASP-NET-MVC). In my mvc 5 app it works great but in core I get this error:

> unable to start process C:\Programs Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe the web
>   server request failed with status error 500 asp.net core

I tried somethings like to delete project start json file, to restart and run as administrator the Visual Studio but no luck. Do I have to add something in my project.json file?
Any idea?

thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that Phalanger requires `System.Web` which is unsupported by ASP.NET Core.

ASP.NET Core doesn't use anything from `System.Web` namespace, as `System.Web` was tightly coupled to IIS and http.sys, which prevented old ASP.NET Web applications to be truly cross-platform. As a consequence of this, configuration via web.config is unsupported too in ASP.NET Core, since it uses a json approach (mix of project.json and appsettings.json).

In addition to that, it would have to support either the new `netstandard1.x` target or `portable-net45+win8` target in order to run with ASP.NET Core on .NET Core.

You'll have to contact the developers and ask about the ASP.NET Core and .NET Core support.